# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]', when converting CType to C#

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

I am doing automatic conversion of code written in VB.NET to C# with SharpDevelop's v4.4 converting tool. VB.NET code for some drag/drop on the form is this:

```
Private Sub me_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragDrop

If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then

    Dim MyFiles() As String = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())

If MyFiles.Length > 0 Then...
```

Converted C# code is such:

```
private void me_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {

        string[] MyFiles = Convert.ToString(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop));

        if (MyFiles.Length > 0)
        {...
```

In C# IDE this line Convert.ToString(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)) is underlined with red and error Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[] is reported.

Telerik tool for converting NET languages makes here the SAME translation.

What is point here, how to get that working in C# and even better: how to write VB.NET code which would be translated correctly?

Comment: `Convert.ToString()` method returns `string`. Why do you want to assign this value to a string array?

Comment: The straightforward translation of working C# back to VB.NET would use `DirectCast` rather than `CType`. You could check if the converters you're using handle that better.

Comment: Yes, definitely, with DirectCast instead of CType conversion goes OK. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want...

```
string[] MyFiles = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
```

..actually... going by most coding standards...

```
string[] myFiles = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
```

As to why it didn't convert properly, it's probably something to ask for support for from the tool vendor.  I can only suggest try casting in VB.NET using [DirectCast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x.aspx) instead of CType see if they do a better job of converting that code.

Comment: This is a better translation of the original VB.NET, and something that will have a chance of actually working, so it's a partial answer. There is indeed (as mentioned in a now-deleted comment) more to the question, though.

Comment: Hi Mick, thanks, that work as expected. But one answer was here and was soon deleted which is also workable.  string[] MyFiles = e.Data.GetFormats(); This is so minimalistic and without no need to cast anything.

Comment: @user973238 That was hopefully deleted because `e.Data.GetFormats()` actually returns something completely different from `e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)`.

Comment: @hvd, thank you for a tip. I will try conversion with DirectCast instead of CType but that need some time. Later I will report here if that is converted OK.

Comment: @hvd GetData(string) returns object, the cast is required...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6a9edsb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Mick I think that was directed at user973238? A deleted answer suggested to use `e.Data.GetFormats()` instead, and that does return `string[]`, so doesn't need a cast, but it doesn't return the data the OP is interested in.

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrect. Look at the following line:

```
Dim MyFiles() As String = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())
```

The important thing here is `String()` at the end. That's an array definition.

So the `e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)` is returning an array.

So the reason it's not working is that `Convert.ToString()` returns a single string. So there is your casting issue. What you want to do is:

```
string[] myFiles = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
```

Comment: As stated in my question TWO of most used converting tools like is SharpDevelop and Telerik convert concrete code at showed way.

Comment: Well. Don't just take code. Read it and understand it.